# JQuery Height of Hidden TR returning 0

Tags: jquery, html, css, html-table

I'm trying to calculate the height of a TR that is set to display:none, however, the jquery height extension method returns 0 everytime.  Of course when its visible it returns the correct value.  From my understanding and past experience, I don't know why this is happening because shouldn't it return the height even if its hidden?  Anyhow, any help would be appreciated!

thanks!

Comment: Maybe you want visibility:hidden to hide the element.  I think that preserves the height in the document.

Answer (score 4):

No, elements that are `display:none` do not take up room in the document space, so have no dimensions.

It's expected then that properties that are calculated from an element's rectangular space (such as `offsetWidth` or `offsetHeight`) will return `0`.

Reference: [CSS1 Formatting model](http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-CSS1/#formatting-model)

**Edit**: getting dimensions of hidden elements is hard. Depending on your situation, [this answer may be of some help.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1473584/need-to-find-height-of-hidden-div-on-page-set-to-displaynone/1473605#1473605)

Comment: how could i get the height of that element then?

Answer (score 1):

Rotatin is right. What I've done in the past when I've really needed to know what the height of an element is, is to use jquery to get the height, store it in the element's data object and then hide the element after the page is loaded.

This will be unsightly for a page with a lot of elements (it will seem to lag because the whole page will have to load before hiding elements).

But, if you need this technique, it can be accomplished as such:

```
$('.should_be_hidden').each(function() {
    $(this).data('height',$(this).height()).hide();
});
```

It's often useful if you need to animate an object.

To obtain the height, when needed... you can just do:

```
var element_height = $('#some_element').data('height');
```