# Trying to calculate .offset while elements display:none reports false height

Tags: jquery, css, offset

I have pages with "tabs" - if you open everything they are very long, but when tabs is activated the page is a lot shorter.

Now I need to accurately calculate the height of the wrapper div (which encloses all these elements) but it reports the value when everything is visible therefore resulting in false values..

Comment: Don't calculate the height until the divs are hidden. Why don't you post some code then we might have a chance of helping.

Comment: check this out: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1473584/need-to-find-height-of-hidden-div-on-page-set-to-displaynone

Answer (score 2):

If your element has `display:none` in css, the browser doesn't bother rendering it at all. In this case, the answer is not directly. In recent jQueries, you can't even get its width or height.

You can get coordinates of `visibility:hidden` element but `display:none` element is excluded from rendering tree. So its position is undefined.