# Can't get element height when using jQuery show scale

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, show-hide

I was wondering if there is a way to get the height of an element when using jQuery's show('scale')

CSS:

```
    #elementid {width:500px;height:500px;}
```

JAVASCRIPT:

```
$('#elementid').show('scale');

alert($("#elementid").height());//This displays "1", instead of "500"
```

Comment: Here are some more details: In this [working example](http://jsfiddle.net/FG9pG/33/), you can see that getting the height after a regular show() works fine. However, when using jQuery UI's show('scale'), the height return is "0", possibly due to a delay?  
LINK: 
http://jsfiddle.net/FG9pG/33/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a bit of research, I was able to find the answer to my question:

```
$('#elementid').show("scale", function()
{
    alert($("#elementid").height());
});
```

The same principal can be used for other animation effects such as slideDown, etc.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
$('#elementid').click (function () {
    alert($('#elementid').height());
});
```

[**WORKING DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/FcJgz/213/)

If the Div is intially Hidden [see here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1473584/need-to-find-height-of-hidden-div-on-page-set-to-displaynone).

Comment: Unfortunately this does not answer my question. I guess I should have mentionned that my div is initially hidden:

Comment: <div id="elementid" style="display:none">some text</div>

Comment: Oh.I see.Added link which you need.

Comment: Sorry, this still doesn't answer my question. I've added some more info in my original post plus this example http://jsfiddle.net/FG9pG/33/