# How to find actual height or width of an HTML element whose display is none

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Some elements in my web application are having display none and I wish to find their actual height to do some computations. I am using jquery 1.6 library to find the height but it returns incorrect value for the height and width of hidden elements havin height in percentage. 
Here is a jsfiddle example for the same: http://jsfiddle.net/LT9fU/
Can anyone suggest the correct way to find the dimensions of hidden HTML elements.

Here is the jsfiddle example for reference

HTML:

```
<body>
<div class="wrapper">
    <div class="vsbl"></div>
    <div class="hdn"></div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.wrapper{
  height:300px;
  width:300px;
  border:1px solid black
}
.vsbl,.hdn{
  height:100px;
  width:70%;
  margin:10px;
  border:1px solid black;     
}
.hdn{
  display:none;
}
```

Javascript:

```
$().ready(function(){
  var content = "";
  content += $(".vsbl").width() + "<br>";
  content += $(".hdn").width();
  document.body.innerHTML += content;
});
```

The output I got were
210 for visible block and 392 for hidden block.

Comment: Not 100% sure but try outerWidth() rather than width()

Comment: You will not get a right width for elements with `display:none`. You could set the elements `opacity:0` to calculate the width. However if you set the width to an absolute value like 100px in the css you can read it from there with `.css('width')`

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1472303/jquery-get-width-of-element-when-not-visible-display-none

Comment: Also, here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1473584/need-to-find-height-of-hidden-div-on-page-set-to-displaynone

Comment: based on the answers from http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1472303/jquery-get-width-of-element-when-not-visible-display-none and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2345784/jquery-get-height-of-hidden-element-in-jquery I prepared two fiddles
http://jsfiddle.net/bsn52/ and http://jsfiddle.net/XcV43/ still the heights are not same for all cases

Answer (score 1):

im not sure how browsers handle hidden elements, but to be sure you could create a span with jQuery, append your element inside and user $(that span).width()

something of this sort:

```
$("<span>" + inner html of your element +"</span>").width();
```

Answer (score 0):

You may not get the size of an element that has `display: none`.

Some alternatives are:

1. Set the element as `visibility: hidden`
2. Position the element outside the viewport (ex: `left:-10000px`)

Answer (score -1):

try this (works without jQuery):

```
<div class="wrapper">
  <div id="vsbl"></div>
  <div id="hdn"></div>
</div>
```

javascript:

```
var content = document.getElementById('hdn').style.width + "<br />";
var content += document.getElementById('hdn').style.height;
document.body.innerHTML += content;
```

I hope it works!