# Getting height of a div with display:none using height() method of jquery

Tags: jquery, html

I have a div with `style="display:none"`. After placing some content inside, i calculate its height using `height()` method of JQuery. This is working fine and returning correct height.

But, I came across this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1473584/need-to-find-height-of-hidden-div-on-page-set-to-displaynone) and came to know that, an element with `style="display:none"` will have 0 height and width. So, ideally, I had to change `'display:none'` to `'visibility:hidden'` and use `height()` method or use other alternatives to get correct height.

But, then, how my code work when calling `height()` method of JQuery on a div `style="display:none"`? Is this going to be a consistent behavior?

In other words, height() method does not differentiate between display:none and display:block. IS this a consistent behavior? offset height is 0 if display is none as expected.

Comment: It returns the value of the active rule, except that some units like `%` can't be calculated, so there you'd get the authored value. Now, why do you want this? `.height()` returns the computed height, which even with block elements may not be its actual rendered height (think of `scale` etc.)

Comment: Though it's javascript, you should be able to figure this out for jquery (duplicate): https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59509409/how-to-get-displaynoneelement-height-using-pure-javascript

Comment: May be I was not clear. height() method does not differentiate between display:none and display:block. offset height is 0  if display is none as expected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`jQuery.height()` and `.width()` do return the computed style of your element, not its actual height and width.

That an element has its `display` set to `none` will only change the fact that relative units can't be calculated, so you'd get `%` values returned as percentage.

Other than that, there is no difference, since **it's only the computed styles** and not the actual size of your element.

Now jQuery will try its best to convert that percent value to an actual `px` number, that is, it will return the computed size of the parent per the ratio set, but this, only to one level depth.

```js
console.log( 'display-none $height', $('#display-none').height() );
console.log( 'display-block $height', $('#display-block').height() );
console.log( 'display-none-deep $height', $('#display-none-deep').height() );
console.log( 'display-none $width', $('#display-none').width() );
console.log( 'display-block $width', $('#display-block').width() );
console.log( 'display-none computed height', getComputedStyle($('#display-none')[0] ).height );
console.log( 'display-block computed height', getComputedStyle($('#display-block')[0] ).height );
console.log( 'display-block real height', $('#display-block')[0].getBoundingClientRect().height );
```

```css
div[id^="display"] { 
  height: 50%;
  width: 200px;
  transform-origin: top left;
  transform: scale(1.5,1.5); /* won't change anything for computed values */
}
#display-none {
  display: none;
}
body{ height: 100vh;  }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="display-none">
  <div id="display-none-deep"></div>
  hidden
</div>
<div id="display-block">visible</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

In jquery **jQuery.height()** returns the actual height of the element which contains the "display: none" OR "visibility: hidden". But it may be changed as per the child and parent element styles.

Please imagine the situation, the HTML page contains only one div and it has **100px** height. Then Jquery.height() returns the value the same for when we applied **"display: none" OR "visibility: hidden"** in the element.

But the difference between the two style properties are:

**"display: none"**: - the tag will not appear in rendering but Jquery can interact with DOM, that's why the function returning the actual height of the element.

**"visibility: hidden"**:- the tag will appear and 100 px height is allocated there and blank space can see in the site.

**For example, in the train seat reservation system 
if you reserved a seat on a train that no one can use that seat 
but in the general compartment, the people can use the seat when it will free.**

So **' display: none' and 'visibility: hidden' has a consistent behavior in jquery**. But the height will increase or decrease for the parent element of the div.

So please select the option as per your requirement, I think that the **display: none** is the correct option for your requirement.